# Detect the open url in Windows Mobile

Tags: windows, compact-framework, mobile

What I want to do is have a background running app on Windows Mobile that can detect when a specific url is opened and perform some task. About the only way I can think of is to watch the cache directory and look for files specific to the site. There might be a way with IE to get the open url information but I doubt it would work the same for Opera. Another way might be with the querying the open processes because there might be url information in the title bar.

I can always have the user turn my app on and off when they go to my site or have the app open the site when they run it but I would like to avoid any extra steps for the user.

Can you think of anyway to detect the open url?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking at the wrong end.  Don't look at it from above the app, but rather from below.  I'd create an [NDIS intermediate passthrough driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee483408.aspx) (the PASSTHRU example that ships with Platform Builder would be a really good starting point) that watches network activity and looks for HTTP GET requests much like a packet sniffer would.  It would be easy to extract the URIs from the packets at that point and you would be able to definitively watch the requests no matter what browser they use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought there might be something like that but I didn't have enough knowledge to do a useful search.